# Vue application request wrong Axios baseURL

Tags: vue.js, axios

I try to create a baseURL from .env.local, but in request I get http://localhost:8083/Contracts/users insted of https://api.EXAMPLE.dev/api/users.

I use npm run serve  ->  http://localhost:8083

Any suggestion, please?

**.env.locale**

```
VUE_APP_ENDPOINT="https://api.EXAMPLE.dev/api"
```

**main.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_ENDPOINT;
```

**Component.vue**

```
  created: function() {
    axios
      .get("/users")
      .then(response => {
        this.items = response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
```

Comment: Is it possible that your `process.env.VUE_APP_ENDPOINT` is `undefined` for some reason when you define your `axios.defaults.baseURL` ? Have you tried to check that?

Comment: Yes, it didn't know how process.env.VUE_APP_ENDPOINT  is, but I define this from .env.local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was no problem with the code, after a restart it worked.

```
npm run serve
```

Answer (score 1):

Try writing

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_ENDPOINT || "https://api.EXAMPLE.dev/api"
```

And for Component.vue file

```
  created: function() {
    axios({
         url: "/users"
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.items = response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Check if this works. May be that can be reason that process.env is not giving correct value.

Comment: It works, but I want to insert the url from .env.local. It's like process.env is null

Comment: As i know **.env.local** should not contain url in quotes (" "). Try removing that and see if it works.

Comment: Is not from " ". I will do more research about it.

Comment: I restart the app. npm run serve, and it works, anyway, thanks for your time!